# Apple watch series 3 microphone stops working after watch OS 6 update

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

After the watch OS 6 update, I can on longer use Siri with the watch or use it to call. It seems like the watch is not able to record any voice.

I have already unpair and pair numerous time. I have also restarted the watch. All in vain.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: There have been a **LOT** of issues with the new versions of iOS 13. It wouldn't surprise me that you have bumped into one. I imagine that Apple will be releasing some point upgrades to iOS, iPadOS, watchOS & tvOS in the near future. If it is possible to restore the Watch back to the previous OS version I would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS update seems to be related. The phone is an iPhone 11.

**iOS 13** - Killed both speaker and microphone (e.g. The Micky watch face stops announcing time; the face time counterparty cannot hear what is spoken to the watch; Siri cannot get user's voice command)

**iOS 13.1** - Speaker works again (The Micky watch face can announce the time). Microphone remains nonfunctional.

**iOS 13.1.1** - Both speaker and microphone stop working.

At the end I have to take the watch to Apply twice. At second visit they took it back for repair.

In summary: The watch needs to be repaired.